# Are symbolic links possible in an Azure Container Instance volumes?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-storage, azure-container-service, certbot

I'm trying to use Certbot to configure SSL certificates for my Azure Container Instances.

Certbot requires symbolic links.

But the azureFile volumes that you can mount with an ACI don't seem to support symbolic links over cifs, and I can't see where one might add the `-o mfsymlinks` (or whatever) to enable symlinks.

The alternative would be to manually mount the volume from inside the container, to take advantage of the `-o mfsymlinks` option in the `mount` command, but as far as I can figure, you can't manually create a cifs mount from inside an ACI because that would require a privileged container which is impossible in ACI.

So I am stuck.

Is there a way to mount a volume in Azure that can handle symbolic links?

Is there a way I could go about this without using volumes?

Or is there a way to use Certbot (or some alternative) that doesn't require symbolic links, that is more Azure/docker friendly?

thanks!

John

Comment: John, did you have any luck with this? I am hitting the exact same problem.

Comment: I had to work around it in the end, writing a script that copied the symlinked target files to another directory, as files rather than as symlinks, and using those files in certbot. It works fine.